# What is the best way to build a DFA from an alphabet {a,b,c}?

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata, nfa

I'm trying to build a DFA over the alphabet {a,b,c} accepting the set of all strings with three consecutive equal letters.

So for example it can accept: aaa, bbb, ccc, abbb, caaac, ccbbbcc, aaabbbc..

I have tried a different ways but it turns into a huge diagram I was wondering if there is a more elegant way on doing this one?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your title says NFA but your question's body says DFA. I will answer both ways to illustrate why that matters.

Consider an NFA first. We only want to accept strings that have three consecutive symbols of the same kind. There are three symbols, so there are three ways this can happen (assuming we recognize the string is going to be accepted after the first occurrence of three consecutive symbols). We can see anything at all, then three of the same symbol, and then anything at all again. An NFA is easy to write down:

```
     __
    /  \                  __
    |  / a,b,c           /  \
    V /                  |  / a,b,c
--->q0--a->q1-a->q4-a-\  V /
    | \-b->q2-b->q5-b-->(q7)
    \---c->q3-c->q6-c-/
```

Our states do the following:

- q0: the initial state accepts any prefix of a's, b's and c's.
- q1, q4: states that may only be visited by strings with aa as a substring
- q2, q5: states that may only be visited by strings with bb as a substring
- q3, q6: states that may only be visited by strings with cc as a substring
- q7: the accepting state that may only be visited by strings with any of aaa, bbb or ccc as a substring.

After reading some prefix of the input string, the NFA nondeterministically branches to check whether the input string contains aaa, bbb or ccc and, if it does, enters q7 and accepts the whatever may remain of the suffix.

To get a DFA, indeed a minimal DFA, I recommend proceeding by the Myhill-Nerode theorem, checking strings in lexicographical order to see if they are distinguishable from strings we have already considered, and so designing our DFA one state at a time.

1. The empty string is distinguishable. It can be followed by any string in L to get a string in L. Call its state [e].
2. The string a is distinguishable from the empty string, as it can be followed by aaL + L to get a string in L. Call its state [a].
3. The strings b and c are likewise distinguishable and have states [b] and [c].
4. The string [aa] is distinguishable as it can be followed by aL + L to get a string in L. Call its state [aa].
5. The strings bb and cc are likewise distinguishable and have states [bb] and [cc].
6. ba and ca are indistinguishable from a; they are followed by the same strings as a to get a string in L.
7. ab/cb and ac/bc are likewise indistinguishable from b and c, respectively.
8. aaa is distinguishable as it can be followed by anything and it remains a string in the language.
9. bbb and ccc are indistinguishable from aaa.
10. all other strings of length 3 are indistinguishable from a, b, c, aa, bb or cc (check this)
11. all strings of length 4 which start with aaa are indistinguishable from shorter strings (check this)

Because we ran out of distinguishable strings, we know we have listed all the necessary states for a minimal DFA and we can write down the answer:

```
               +---a--->[a]<---a----+
               | +-c--->[c]<---c-+  |
               | |               |  |
     +----b--->[b]-------b------>[bb]---b----+
     |                                       |
     |         +---b--->[b]<---b----+        |   +--+
     |         | +-c--->[c]<---c-+  |        |   |  a,b,c
     |         | |               |  |        V   V  |
--->[e]---a--->[a]-------a------>[aa]---a--->[aaa]--+
     |                                       ^
     |         +---a--->[a]<---a----+        |
     |         | +-b--->[b]<---b-+  |        |
     |         | |               |  |        |
     +----c--->[c]-------c------>[cc]---c----+
```

(The states [a], [b] and [c] are duplicated twice each in order to make the diagram prettier. As it is, the state transition graph isn't planar and it would be confusing to render at all, let alone in ASCII art).

Note that this has the same number of states as the simple NFA we wrote down - this just happens to do away with the non-determinism.

- The way we got the transitions was by going from state [x] to state [y] on symbol s is by seeing whether xs is indistinguishable from z.
- The way we got the initial state is that it's always [e].
- The way we got the accepting state is it's the only one whose strings can be followed be e to get a string in L.

Comment: I don't understand how you're working the --a,c-->  ,  ---b,c-->, ---a,b-->

Comment: @DictatorBoy These transitions handle the case where you started seeing a's, b's or c's but then saw something else and had to "start over". As I noted in parentheses, I duplicated states [a], [b] and [c] to make the diagram neater, but the duplicates (no transitions out) represent the real ones (with transitions out).

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to make neat, but this dot [diagram](https://www.planttext.com/?text=TP9D3e8m48NtFSK4j_K41iFEGnWNRqgZHY04S4Muksq56ihGvVT-Cfssw0TqmxUkLFb-TcXVTADHANB7qlbAe7i5jbMU8Ni4Z8053iTRzFr6YKsySfuJ7B30EMtYJPDPkPaJ9c21cxJ9B4sUxWRMh5S3vA4XJu0Zk-2FbzzlaULwFh8B_hYHlTyaKyP57VZJmD8_TcW-UO_QNiXEwfGoQ69DHbAyv3Kd2YdWZrE9VKgMZ5pcdtPIQY9LsAPqN_m7) is a least traceable.

Comment: @TomBlodget A good example of the sort of rat's nest I was hoping to avoid. Maybe this is a case where the table would have been a better way to go.